# Is there a way to get one or more variables from an input using regular expressions?

Tags: python

Let's say I have a program which has inputs like this

> string**28**something**8**words**2000**

I want to fetch that date embedded it the string so I can get:

```
day = 28
month = 8
year = 2000
```

How can I implement this using regular expressions?

The month 8 can not be explicitly a number but also written as "august".

This is not the case of the marked as duplicate which has no optionals.

If I get a list containing:

> string**28**something**august**words**2000**

With that solution I get only `[28, 2000]` and if the number is equal or minor to 12 there is no way to know if it was a month or a day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `re.findall`:

```
s = 'string28something8words2000'
day, month, year = map(int, re.findall('\d+', s))
```